# I want to add date in R Code comments that automatically update each time I save the R Code file?

Tags: r, rstudio, comments

I am working on R code with a team, where I want to put a time stamp on comments to track last change, or update. Thoug I am using github to main version history, but for team easy reference to add laste update time stamp in the code.
How can i achieve, I am using R studio on windows 11 machine.

I doing it manully by entry date in comment line. I am looking for a code that update the comment eachtime I save R code.

Comment: I don't know of anything that does exactly this, but one semi-manual option could be to use something like this: https://community.rstudio.com/t/feature-request-timestamp-in-iso8601-ish-format/7613

Comment: For the effort vs. payoff, I would go with snippet option mentioned by @Jon Spring. If you really want to go down the rabbit hole though, you could define a pre-commit git hook that runs a script (could be R or strictly shell) that parses all the changed files, looks for a pattern, replaces the pattern with the new timestamp, rewrites the file, and then recommits it. Gets complicated fast. Not sure, but maybe a linter could do all of this too.